# Como centralizar um input em um grid no Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap, grid

Olá, pessoal.

Estou começando com a programação web front-end e tenho uma dúvida com relação ao Bootstrap 4,  e o seu sistema de grid. Basicamente como centralizar o `input` e o `p` dentro do Grid.

Tenho o código abaixo:

```
    <div class="container-fluid mt-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-1">
                <a href="http://placehold.it"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 pt-5">
               <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

O que quero basicamente é centralizar esse `input` e o `p` dentro do grid, de modo que fique ao lado da imagem de 200x150 (Que ao aumentar a imagem, o tamanho da `row` também aumenta, deixando os outros elementos na parte de cima). Consegui fazer isso colocando dentro da classe `<div class="col-md-6">` o `pt-5`, porém ele da um padding-top de 5, ficando meio que uma "gambiarra" e não centralizando dentro do Grid corretamente.

Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de centralizar o input sem precisar usar o `pt-5` dentro da classe pra fazer o espaçamento da parte de cima.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o text-align:center nas divs pai, exemplo:

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-1">
            <a href="http://placehold.it"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 pt-5" style="text-align:center">
           <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align:center">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta. Basicamente não atende o que preciso, pois o que quero é centralizar no meio do Grid de forma com que altere o padding e gostaria de saber se há alguma classe para isso, não apenas mudar a orientação do parágrafo/imagem para o centro.

Comment: Você tá querendo centralizar verticalmente em relação ao tamanho da imagem?

Comment: Isso, pretendo centralizar o formulário e o parágrafo verticalmente em relação ao tamanho da imagem que ocupa as duas primeiras colunas.

Answer (score -1):

Pode usar display Flex no pai (imagem)
Ex:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  font: 20px arial;
  color: #000;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;

  /* habilita o flex nos filhos diretos */
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  /* centraliza na vertical */
  -ms-align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  /* centraliza na horizontal */
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper div {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      Exemplo de alinhamento
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```